# Dynamiclly generated rows not added to table html

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am wondering why if I add a new row to table using Jquery , the newly added row is not added to table if I check the source code of the page.
I want a way to add the new row to the table.
here is the jquery code:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
            $("table >tbody").append($('<tr>')).append($('<td>')).append("new row");
        });
```

and table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  // create a <tr> element:
  $('<tr>', {
    // set its html:
    'html' : '<td>New row</td>'
  // append the <tr> to the <tbody>:
  }).appendTo('table > tbody');
});
```

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $('<tr>', {
    'html' : '<td>New row</td>'
  }).appendTo('table > tbody');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">button</button>
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The reason that your original code:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("table > tbody").append($('<tr>')).append($('<td>')).append("new row");
});
```

didn't work is because `append()` returns the element to which the new content was appended (in this case the `<tbody>`, so all elements, and the textContent, are appended to that element (creating invalid HTML).

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("table > tbody").append($('<tr>')).append($('<td>')).append("new row");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">button</button>
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

References:

- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Comment: But why i am not able to see the newly added row if I click the view page source of the browser?

Comment: Because you're looking at the HTML source, which is not updated; you need to look at the DOM to see the updates. Use your browser's web developer tools (F12 in most browsers, or right click the element and select 'Inspect element').

Comment: ok. If I want to delete a particular row which is added in dom not in html, what should i do?

Comment: This 'accepted answer' may have worked back in the day. But I'm using jQuery 3.2.1 and  I copied your exact code -- it does NOT appear in my 'view source'.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<table id="yourtableid"><tbody></tbody><table>

$("#button").click(function(){
   $("#yourtableid tbody").append($('<tr>')).append($('<td>')).text("new row");
});
```

[TEST HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/LkrxLad1/)